# react-native[ios] native-base picker TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

native-base picker shows following error when there is only one picker.item
[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXm8c.png)

**Following code does not work**

```
<Picker
      iosHeader="Select one"
      mode="dropdown"
      selectedValue={this.state.selected1}
      onValueChange={this.onValueChange.bind(this)}
    >
      <Picker.Item label="Wallet" value="key0" />
    </Picker>
```

**Following code work**

```
<Picker
      iosHeader="Select one"
      mode="dropdown"
      selectedValue={this.state.selected1}
      onValueChange={this.onValueChange.bind(this)}
    >
      <Picker.Item label="Wallet" value="key0" />
      <Picker.Item label="Wallet" value="key1" />
    </Picker>
```

**Version**

react-native: 0.54.4

native-base: 2.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reported this issue on [native-base github repository](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/1918) and they have marked it as a bug in library.Follow the [link](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/1918) for solution